# Gradle console in Android studio is not updated

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I do not know if it is by design or not.  When I start Android Studio, Gradle Console shows a long list of tasks executed with the following in the end:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4.12 secs
```

When I run a gradle task (e.g. assembleRelease), the Run window shows a tree of tasks with "Run build" as the root, and the time of each task updated in real-time.  However, Gradle Console never changes. It remains the same until Android Studio is restarted. In other words, it is useful only for showing the results of initial tasks after Android Studio is started.

This is the case only after AS was upgraded to V2.2

Could anyone offer a tip on how to see the sequence of tasks?